# Objective-C Random int

Tags: objective-c, random, int

Example, I have 2 ints and 1 output.

```
    int IntNumberOne = 100;
    int IntNumberTwo = 30;

    NSLog(@"");
```

I would like the output to display just ONE of the two ints, and randomize every time this program is started.
How would that be done?

Comment: Well I, what I tried just looked rubbish and was more pure for the 'try'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arc4random() function to pick number randomly:

```
NSLog(@"%d", arc4random()%2 ? IntNumberOne : IntNumberTwo);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. So what would happen if I change %2 to %3 ?

Comment: @Marnix, in that case you'll have 3 possible options to pick from and switch/case block will be more suitable to use there

Comment: You can read up on the modulus or modulo operator (%) at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation or http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html